# Tengo 2 Funciones similares en una me dice Undefined Variable

Tags: laravel-8

estoy haciendo en laravel una especie de blog y en 2 archivos tengo el mismo código (similar)... en uno funciona bien y en el 2ndo me dice: Undefined variable $image_name... en la linea $data['photo']= $image_name.'.'.$ext;

Copie y pegue el codigo de PostController en CategoryController, pero en este segundo falla, en el primero funciona bien... que puede estar pasando?

PostController (Funciona Bien...)

```
$data=$request->all();

        $slug=Str::slug($request->title);
        $author=Auth::user()->id;
        $count=Post::where('slug',$slug)->count();
        if($count>0){
            $slug=$slug.'-'.date('ymdis').'-'.rand(0,999);
        }
        $data['slug']=$slug;
        $data['added_by']=$author;

        $tags=$request->input('tags');
        if($tags){
            $data['tags']=implode(',',$tags);
        }
        else{
            $data['tags']='';
        }

        if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
            $image_name = Str::random(20);
            $ext = strtolower($request->file('photo')->getClientOriginalExtension());
            $image_full_name = $image_name.'.'.$ext;
            $upload_path = 'image/';
            $image_url = $upload_path.$image_full_name;
            $success = $request->file('photo')->move($upload_path,$image_full_name);
        }

        $data['photo']= $image_name.'.'.$ext;

        $status=Post::create($data);
```

CategoryController

```
$data= $request->all();
        $slug=Str::slug($request->title);
        $count=Category::where('slug',$slug)->count();
        if($count>0){
            $slug=$slug.'-'.date('ymdis').'-'.rand(0,999);
        }
        $data['slug']=$slug;

        if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
            $image_name = Str::random(20);
            $ext = strtolower($request->file('photo')->getClientOriginalExtension());
            $image_full_name = $image_name.'.'.$ext;
            $upload_path = 'image/';  
            $image_url = $upload_path.$image_full_name;
            $success = $request->file('photo')->move($upload_path,$image_full_name);
        }

        $data['photo']= $image_name.'.'.$ext;
        
        $data['is_parent']=$request->input('is_parent',0);
        // return $data;   
        $status=Category::create($data);
```

Comment: la linea $data['photo'] = $image_name.'.'.$text; Deberia estar dentro del if hasFile, ya que la variable $image_name solo existirá si se cumple la condición

Comment: Hola, si acabo de darme cuenta de ese detalle, pero mas trastornado me quedo aun... pensando en porque en el otro controlador funciona igualmente

Comment: prueba con enviar formulario con archivo y después otro sin archivo en el primer controlador. ¿Que te sale?

Comment: Bien, si en el primer controlador no envio ningun archivo me salta el mismo error.

En el segundo controlador puse la funcion dentro del if hasFile.. y sube la imagen y todo, pero en la base de datos me guarda el nombre con el que subo el archivo y no el Str.. y tampoco sube la imagen....... solamente guarda el nombre original del archivo en la tabla.

Comment: Apa, creo que encontre el problema estaba en el form... me faltaba el enctype :D